# Low represented data in dataset

Tags: regression, sampling, svm, bootstrap

I am trying to create a regression model (SVM) for certain data. The dataset consists of few subsets being a representation of different elements. However literature says they can be combined into one dataset and used for regression as one dataset. My problem is that I have one large subset, and the remaing subsets which are small. This disproportion makes it impossible to make a good regression model for the data which is not well represented in the sample.

I thought of few approaches: 
1. bagging
2. To multiply the values of the sample which come from poorly represented elements

Could this help? Are there any other techniqies I could possibly use?

Comment: This is a problem of *balancing* -- have you tried searching towards techniques for addressing balance in SVM training? A quick search should turn up a fair number of results ....